# cv2 (2.4.8) missing DIST_L2 for distanceTransform?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to implement a image segmentation node.  If I following the image segementation example code

```
 dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DIST_L2'
```

Checking the _*dict* there is not a DIST_L2.  I tried substituting NORM_L2, but that did not give the expected result.

The "import cv2" gives me version 2.4.8  (as installed by ROS Jade on Ubuntu 14.04)

Has anyone seen this issue?

Is it possible to use OpenCV 3  in python, or is that only for C++?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230811/cv2-(2.4.8)-missing-dist_l2-for-distancetransform?/) by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2016-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-04-03**:
Can you write a minimal script which demonstrates this behavior. You have not clarified what cv2 exactly is. And point to the documentation from which you believe that cv2.DIST_L2 should exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is more a StackOverflow question, or [OpenCV Q&A](http://answers.opencv.org/questions/) as the library itself is independent from ROS, and the answer can also be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029401/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-dist-l2) and [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/91808/dist_l2-missing-in-version-248-segmentation-demo-fails/).

Try with:

```
cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2
```

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2016-04-04**:
Supposedly OpenCV 3 is installed with Jade.  The directions for using with C++ seem straightforward with CMake, but I'm not sure about Python.

Does OpenCV 3 work with Python in the Jade installation?

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-04-04**:
AFAIK Ubuntu Opencv 3 cannot be installed directly on Ubuntu 14.04 (using apt-get) so I guess that Jade will use Opencv2 instead.